# How to completely wipe 3rd generation iPod Nano

Tags: ipod, ipod-nano

I was using Floola to transfer songs to my 3rd generation iPod Nano and it suddenly stopped working. Now I installed iTunes and I can't seem to be able to delete any of the old songs and I cannot delete them manually. Even my iPod can't see them anymore and classifies them as “other”. How can I wipe the hard drive and start again fresh?

Answer (score 1):

iTunes should be able to "Restore iPod"

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: @The.Lonely.Idiot does it display an error?

Comment: Nope, it updated just fine, but it still shows that there is only 1.1 GB available.